# I came up with this SQL structure to allow rolling back and auditing user information, will this be adequate?

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I came up with an idea to store my user information and the updates they make to their own profiles in a way that it is always possible to rollback (as an option to give to the user, for auditing and support purposes, etc.) while at the same time improving (?) the security and prevent malicious activity.

My idea is to store the user's info in rows but never allow the API backend to delete or update those rows, **only to insert new ones that should be marked as the "current" data row**. I created a graphical explanation:

[image]
[Schema image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZ282.png)

**The potential issues** that I come up with this model is the fact that users may update the information too frequently, **bloating up the database** (1 million users and an average of 5 updates per user are 5 million entries). However, for this **I came up with the idea of putting apart the rows with "false" in the "current" column through partitioning**, where they should not harm the performance and will await to be cleaned up every certain time.

**Am I right to choose this model? Is there any other way to do such a thing?**

Comment: Just make a regular table with settings. Whenever you insert/update you immediately after **also** >add< a row to a history table (so 2 tables `user_settings` and `user_settings_history`) with the exact same values. This way you'll automatically have a history table with the last entry being ALSO the current *and* a table with *only* current values. Add a 'changedate' field to the history table (and a 'changed_by' etc.) for some more relevant historic info that can be of use later on.

Answer (score 2):

I'd also use a second table `user_settings_history`.

When a setting is created, INSERT it in the `user_settings_history` table, along with a timestamp of when it was created. Then also UPDATE the same settings in the `user_settings` table. There will be one row per user in `user_settings`, and it will always be the current settings.

So the `user_settings` would always have the current settings, and the history table would have all prior sets of settings, associated with the date they were created.

This simplifies your queries against the `user_settings` table. You don't have to modify your queries to filter for the `current` flag column you described. You just know that the way your app works, the values in `user_settings` are defined as current.

If you're concerned about the `user_settings_history` table getting too large, the timestamp column makes it fairly easy to periodically DELETE rows over 180 days old, or whatever number of days seems appropriate to you.

By the way, 5 million rows isn't so large for a MySQL database. You'd want your queries to use an index where appropriate, but the size alone isn't disadvantage.